# Which Azure products are needed for a staging database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, etl, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I have several external data APIs that I access using some Python scripts. My scripts run from an on-premises server, transform the data, and store it in a SQL Server database on the same server. I suppose it's a rudimentary ETL system run with Python and T-SQL.

The system is about to grow quite a bit with new APIs and will require more complex data pipelines (for example, some of the API data will be spun off to more than one table). I think this would be a good time to move the system onto Azure (we are heavily integrated with Microsoft so it will have to be Azure!).

I have spent a few days researching the Azure products that would let me run Python scripts to access data from web APIs and store the processed data in a cloud database. I'm looking for advice on what sort of Azure products other people have used for similar jobs. At the moment it seems I will need:

1. Azure SQL Database to hold the processed data that can be accessed by various colleagues.
2. Azure Data Factory to manage, log, and schedule the pipeline jobs and to run my custom Python scripts (is this even possible?).
3. Azure Batch to run the aforementioned Python scripts but I'm not sure about this.

I want to put together a proposal basically and start thinking about costs but it would be good to hear from someone who has done something similar - am I on the right track or completely off? Should I just stay on-premises? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse are good for relational data. And if you want to use NoSQL, you could go with Azure Cosmos DB. If you want to use Files to store data, you could use Azure Data Lake.
2. For python scripts, you could use [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) or [Data bricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python) for Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Warehouse should be used if the amount of data you want to load is in petabytes. Also, Azure Data warehouse is not meant for complex transformations. I would recommend it for plain data load with PolyBase.